# UI Testing external OS X application using xcode 7.2.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a custom Cocoa Based app on my Mac OS X 10.11 but I don't have the source code for it. I want to run UI Tests on it using Xcode 7.2.1 's UI Testing feature.

What I want to know is that how can I make my UI Test launch the target application and then record the steps that are then executed?

Comment: Just wanted to know if someone found something on this?

Comment: I think there is no way to test an application without it's source code in Xcode 7.2.1. We need the actual source code of the application to use the UI Testing feature of Xcode 7.2.1